# Several footnotes in the section heading

Tags: footnotes

How can I insert two footnotes in the section headings?

```
\chapter[aaa]{aaa\protect\footnotemark\footnotemark}

\footnotetext{some text1}
\footnotetext{some text2}
```

When I use this syntax, I come up with a 12 appearing on the top of aaa (without any comma between 1 and 2) and both of the footnotes on the bottom of the page are numbered 2!

How can I change the numbers to symbols in the footnote?

Comment: If possible, don't footnote titles; one footnote to a title is already too much, two are evil. I know this is used in some academic fields, but from a typographic point of view (and from the reader's point of view too) this is really bad.

Comment: @egreg -- i agree about the undesirability of footnotes in titles.  but what is an acceptable alternative, if a citation or reference *must* be given?

Comment: @barbarabeeton The first paragraph, for instance. Of course no footnote would be even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `multiple` and `symbol` options of the `footmisc` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[multiple,symbol]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\chapter[aaa]{aaa\footnote{First note.}\footnote{Second note.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Yet the problem is partly solved. When I use this syntax, only the second footnote is displayed at the bottom of the page!