# Multiple footnotes on chapter title

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to add multiple footnotes in the chapter title but only one of them appears on the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tamuconfig}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point    
\usepackage{amssymb}% Package to draw a square in the formulas    
\usepackage{wasysym}% Package to draw a square in the figures
\usepackage{amsmath} % or simply amstext
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[multiple,symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\textheight=80pt% only for the example

\begin{document}

\chapter[nine]{SUMMARY AND CONCLUSIONS\footnote{one}\footnote{two}}

\end{document}
```

In my tamuconfig.sty file I have a line of code as

```
    \usepackage[rm, tiny, center, compact]{titlesec}
```

I think that is what messes up with footnote. I appreciate it if anybody knows how can I fix this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry about it. I just fixed it.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile. You need to load `amsmath` before `waysym` and you're loading `footmisc` twice with conflicting options. What is your purpose of loading it anyway? Also, since `tamuconfig` has only one line, replace it in your example with the line.

Comment: For those who might have similar questions: I found the answer here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136982/several-footnotes-in-the-section-heading